# Usar fadeOut('slow') em Array Ajax que contem diversos id

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Olá,

Tenho uma função em ajax, no qual faço uma remoção de várias linhas em uma tabela html.

A função coleta diversos `id` que serão deletados, eu gostaria de fazer um `fadeOut('slow')` quando a função for executada.

### Parte da Tabela

```
<tr id="<?php echo $produto['idarquivo']; ?>" >
```

Este `id` já está sendo coletado na função `ajax`, eu gostaria de usar o efeito na parte onde a tabela é removida.

### Código JS com a Função Ajax

(tentei fazer o `fadeOut('slow')` ser executado, mas eu não consegui (já testei no depurador e a função ajax de deletar é executada).

```
$('#btn_delete').click(function(){

    if(confirm("Deseja deletar as linhas selecionadas?"))
    {
        var id = '';

        $('.checkbox:checked').each(function(){
            id += $(this).val()+',';
        });

        if(id == '' || id == ',') 
        {
            alert("Selecione uma linha para deletar");
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
             url:'deletar.php',
             type:'POST',
             data:{ids:id},
             success:function()
             {
                for(var i=0; i<id.length; i++)
                {
                    $('tr#'+id[i]+'').css('background-color', '#ccc');
                    $('tr#'+id[i]+'').fadeOut('slow');
                }
            }

        });
    }

}
else
{
    return false;
}
});
```

### deletar.php

```
<?php include_once('conexao.php');

$ids = $_POST['ids'];

print_r($ids);

$exp = explode(",", $ids);

foreach($exp as $id){

    $query = "DELETE FROM arquivo WHERE idarquivo = '$ids'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($con, $query);
}

?>
```

Comment: O que tem nesse `id`? o que dá `console.log(typeof id, id);`?

Comment: @Sergio ele está retornando `undefined` porém o código deleta normalmente as linhas que contém os `id` que são passados. Atualizei meu código com o `js` completo que coleta os `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minha sugestão é, em vêz de teres uma string de `id`s assim: `foo,bar,baz` teres isso numa array e tratar tudo como uma array/coleção...

Assim:

```js
$('#btn_delete').click(function() {
  if (confirm("Deseja deletar as linhas selecionadas?")) {
    var ids = $('.checkbox:checked').map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get();

    if (ids.length == 0) {
      alert("Selecione uma linha para deletar");
    } else {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'deletar.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          ids: JSON.stringify(ids)
        },
        success: function() {
          for (var i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
            $('tr#' + id[i]).css('background-color', '#ccc').fadeOut('slow');
          }
        }
      });
    }
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: seu código funcionou para a questão de usar o `fadeOut('slow')` eu tive apenas que colocar `ids` ao invés de `id` nas linhas: `for (var i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
            $('tr#' + id[i]).css('background-color', '#ccc').fadeOut('slow');` porém o meu arquivo `deletar.php` parou de funcionar. Eu postei ele aqui, sabe me dizer o que houve?

Comment: @Wendell o problema é que agora envias um JSON, testa fazer assim no PHP: `$exp = json_decode($ids);`